# byte order in xmm clang assembly comments

Tags: c, assembly, clang, sse, endianness

Given the following program:

```
#include "emmintrin.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    volatile __m128i x = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I can get the assembly using `clang -O -S test.c` (only listing the interesting part):

```
...
movl    $1, %eax
movd    %rax, %xmm0
pslldq  $8, %xmm0               # xmm0 = zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,xmm0[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
...
```

According to the manual of [_mm_set_epi64x](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_set_epi&expand=4562,4565,4567), `%xmm0` should be `[0, 1, 0, 0]`, with each element being an integer (32 bits).

However, according to the comment, `%xmm0` holds `[0, 0, 0, 1]`. I don't think endianness is relevant here, for I am only looking at a register.

I suspect that it's sth related to the notation used by clang assembly comment, but I can't find any useful info on it on the internet.

== Edit:

Filed a [bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=28109) to clang.

Answer (score 1):

The clang code loads the value in two steps. First, the value 1 is loaded into the lower 64 bits of the register. Then the entire thing is left shifted by 8 binary places so the value 1 ends up in the high 64 bits just as your code specifies.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding as well. However, the comment `# xmm0 = zero ...` doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk The comment refers to the pre state of `xmm0`, which, before the shift is executed, does indeed contain 1 in the lowest position.

Comment: That would be very counter intuitive. `xmm0 = zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,xmm0[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` reads like an assignment. `volatile __m128i y = _mm_set1_epi32(1);` => `movaps  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = [4294967297,4294967297]` shows that the comment reflects the state of a register afterwards, not prior state, IMO.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk look at other examples of commentated clang output. The comments always show what the operands contain before the instruction. I know it's slightly weird but it kinda makes sense.

Comment: The example I gave in my previous comment shows that the comments reflects the state afterwords. Could you provide an example showing the state of operands before the instruction?

Comment: In this case, consider raising a bug against clang.

Answer (score 1):

The comment appears to be describing the operation of `pslldq` in terms of the previous contents of `xmm0` (even though those are known at compile time).

It seems to be in reverse order from the usual high-element-first (`[ 3 2 1 0 ]`) that `_mm_set` uses, and that makes "left" shifts make sense.

It's the byte-order you'd get in memory if you stored the vector.

I forget if that's typical for clang, and I don't have time right now to check another example.